# Javascript - bind to keys events, except if user is in a text input

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have this page, in which the user can use the directional keys to navigate between different items. For that, I use a jquery binder :

```
$(document.body).bind('keydown', function(event) {
// use the directional keys
```

I want this event work at every time, except if the user is focused in a text input.

So I tried to filter out the event like this:

```
$(document.body).bind('keydown', '*:not(input[type="text"], textarea)', function(event) {
```

but unfortunately the filter does not work, and the event fires in every case.

I could detect the focus (and blur) events on every input in my page, and deactivate the move event via a global boolean, however I find it quite inelegant.

Is there a way to either let the input fields "consume" the events, or to filter the event with a reverse selector like I tried to do ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: The given code works when the correct function `.on()` is used instead of `.bind()` http://jsfiddle.net/1w0em16n/1/

Comment: Well I don't know; I tested both (on firefox and chrome), and the event fires with each

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't make the selector on `on()` work, so I finally solved the problem by filtering on event.target after reception:

```
$(document.body).on('keydown', function(event) {
    if (!$(event.target).is('input[type="text"], textarea')){
    // handle keys...
```

(the solution was proposed by someone who deleted his answer, so I retrace it here)

Answer (score 2):

That isn't valid `.bind()` syntax. Events passed to `.bind()` cannot be delegated.

You probably mean to use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$(document.body).on('keydown', '*:not(input[type="text"], textarea)', function(event) {

});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/oGeez/okkLb4s0/)

If you are using a jQuery version prior to `.on()` (which you shouldn't be..) you can use [`delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/):

```
$(document.body).delegate('*:not(input[type="text"], textarea)', 'keydown', function(event){

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip; however with both 'on' and 'bind', the event fires regardless of the condition... Finally I filtered myself on the event's target